Elemental novel where a boy is shown he can control elements and ends up being really strong at the end
I read this book a while back, before quarantine is all I know.
It was a book that began with the main character accidentally destroying a cafeteria table. It's explained that it was because of his lightning powers by a classmate. The classmate brings him to a group of other kids his age who are taught by this teacher.
The teacher teaches them about their elemental powers and has made a "gun" that helps focus their power to amplify the control. Later on shown to not have worked at all and only seemed like it did cause it worked like a mental charm for the protagonist.
The end has the main character figure out that he is actually really strong(I believe the book said he was a "Tier 9" controller) and was on the level where he could control tornadoes.
Mainly trying to find the book and if it ended up having a sequel.

"Storm of Lightning" by Richard Paul Evans?
